# Java (NOT ANDROID) send AT volume command through Bluetooth to headset

Tags: java, bluetooth

Ok, disclaimer: Normally, I provide code and attempts but this one is beyond me. I have messed with BlueCove a little and found a working stack for Mac but I'm not sure this is the direction I need to go.

I have googled, but Android links saturate this topic.

Bottom line: I have a device with broken volume buttons that has a default volume setting at about 75% or so. I just want to whip together a Java app to send AT+VGS command to the connected device.

Thanks for bearing with me.

UPDATE: Ok a little bit of code:

```
    try{
        LocalDevice localDevice = LocalDevice.getLocalDevice();
        System.out.println("Device:" + localDevice.getBluetoothAddress());
        DiscoveryAgent agent = localDevice.getDiscoveryAgent();
        agent.startInquiry(DiscoveryAgent.GIAC, listener);
        try {
            synchronized(lock){
                lock.wait();
            }
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
        System.out.println("Device Inquiry Completed. Number of listners:" + listener.devices.size());
    }
```

Returns:

```
Device:000000000007
Device Inquiry Completed. Number of listners:0
```

So I assume I'm finding my local BT but it doesn't see anything out there. I have the device paired and connected. Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track, the stack is the way to handle it, you have to send AT commands to your Headset.[image]